# How do I detect a windows event from a google chat message with python?

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, pywin32, win32com

I can use the below code to get google calendar events from chrome:

```
h = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(None, "System")
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
for record in win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(h, flags, 0):
    if record.EventID == 10016:
        print("it's a google calendar event (or something similar)!")
```

I can't figure out how to detect an event that's generated by google chat running in chrome. I've tried log sources other than system and using an event viewer to try to find the event, but I can't seem to find it even though it shows up in action center (chat icon in very bottom right of windows taskbar).

How can I find the event? Or is it possible there is no windows event but it still shows in action center?

Comment: "*Or is it possible there is no windows event but it still shows in action center?*" - this; I don't think there is any relation between toast notifications and eventlogs. What is the event 10016 you are searching for? It [looks like a DCOM Error code](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=eventid+10016&ia=web)

Comment: yes it is a DCOM error, god knows why windows is built to just throw errors for normal notifications by default. It might be possible to change some settings so it doesn't come through as an error. Do you have any idea how I can get the events from action center?